# #nginxhelp Reverse Proxy to Microsoft IIS Server with Windows Authentication on the Application

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Server :Ubuntu: 18.04.4
Hosting Server: NGINX: 1.16.1

A school needs to publish their learning management system to the Internet so teachers/students can learn from home.

I am a Network Engineer and I have very little experience with NGINX and reverse proxy servers in general, apart from setting firewall rules.

So, I have had this almost working.  My first config seems to work, it passes the traffic so it seems, and I get the login prompt, but when entering valid credentials I get an authentication error.

I found some suggestions that this is due to NTLM authentication.
I found some further information that suggested I needed to use `streams`.  I tried this, and don't even get any authentication prompt at all.

So, I did contact NGINX to see if I needed NGINX Plus, but they said I should post here first to see if someone knows how to make this work.
The first config attempt is below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name URL.URL.URL/daymap;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/CERTNAME.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private2/KEYNAME.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # curl https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ffdhe2048.txt > /path/to/dhparam
    # ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam;

    # intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

    resolver 172.31.4.10;

    #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

location / {

        proxy_pass_header Authorisation;
        proxy_pass http://URL.URL.URL.URL.URL/daymap/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_buffering off;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
        proxy_redirect off;
   }

}
```

The Stream config is below:

```
stream {
    upstream backend {
        hash $remote_addr consistent;

        server URL.URL.URL:443 weight=5;
        server IP.IP.IP.IP:443            max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    upstream dns {
       server 172.31.4.10:53;
       server 172.31.4.11:53;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
        proxy_timeout 3s;
        proxy_pass backend;
    }

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:53 udp reuseport;
        proxy_timeout 20s;
        proxy_pass dns;
    }
    resolver 172.31.4.10;
}
```

I'll appreciate any insight. Hopefully, someone can see what I am doing wrong.
Regards,
Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This began working all by itself about 4 days after posting this.  The streams config is the one that is working.
Hope that might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

proxying NTLM is not easy. An NTLM authentication requeries a single connection established between the client and the server. The ussage of keepalive connections will not work in this case.

For more details about how to authenticate using NTLM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_protocols/ms-grvhenc/b9e676e7-e787-4020-9840-7cfe7c76044a

In NGINX Plus (commercial subscription) there is a special directive to tell the proxy server NTLM is in place.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ntlm

This directive is only available in NGINX Plus. With NGINX OSS you can work with streams module instead of http to work arround the keepalives for the backend connections.

Let me know if you need more help on this.

Comment: Hi Timo, thanks for your advice.  Actually, it was NGINX themselves who said you don't need NGINX Plus just to proxy for NTLM authentication.  
That came from their solution architect here in Australia.
It actually started working all by itself about 4 days after posting this, and has been working happily since then.
I think the IIS server restarted, and after that, it has been working.